Routing to a link in Vuejs directly after it has been deployed on netlify
I created a Vuejs/Vuetify and Vue router site, after I deployed it to netlify, if I try to go to a link direct netlify brings up a page not found screen, what can I do?
I don't know what else to do, cos when I tried putting '_redirects' with the code
/*  /index.html 200
But it still didn't redirect

Where exactly did you put '_redirects' file?  It's not meant to just go anywhere, it should go in the public folder. When you build the app for production you should see it in the root folder (dist) of your production build.

You wrote you using a Vue Router so when you mean with "...if I try to go to a link direct..." you navigate through the vue router then maybe this helps.
I had the same after deploying to vercel.
I found out you can add settings for vercel in the project. Maybe there is smth similiar for netlify.
In my case I added a vercel.json in the project and add this rewrite logic
{
    "rewrites": [
        {
            "source": "/(.*)",
            "destination": "/"
        }
    ]
}


Thanks a lot! But I found a fix, someone commented it
